# i have a file and using for loop to echo the statement as per the value

Tags: linux, shell, unix

if the number is less than <=25 and not below 0 then echo "certificate will expire in 25 days"
if number is less than 0 or negative then echo "already expired"
else echo no certificate will expire in 25 days.

using the below script but not getting desired output

```
        if [[ "$noofdays"<=25 ]] && [[ "$noofdays">=0 ]]
        then
        ALERT=$(echo "Certificate will expire in $noofdays days")
        elif [[ "$noofdays"<=0 ]]
        then
        ALERT='Certificate already expired'
        else
        ALERT='Certificate will not expire within 25 days'
        fi
```

Comment: This script is working fine, please check if value of `noofdays` is assigned correctly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the exact input and corresponding output. I suggest to add a line like `printf "<%s>\n" "$noofdays"` and copy&paste the output to the question.